# Probability of a point fitting a line

Tags: r, regression, fitting

I am trying to classify between two groups a set of points given two variables (size of the space = L and points of the space occupied = N).

At the moment I have a sample size of 620 samples with their size and number of points covered and a training set of labelled samples coming from the two groups I want to classify (trendy / unpopular).

I want to use the value r = N/L to classify new points.

The picture of my current situation is this:

[image]

The x axis is the N value and y is the L value, in red the samples labelled as popular and unpopular in green.

My goal now is to classify the blue points as popular, unpopular or undefined (if they are in a zone that is not clear for example).

Following some internet posts I found a solution could be to use the next formula:

[image]

Where we consider two different r, rP = 0.8 and rU = 0.012, rP being the mean of the N/L for all the popular gold set and rU the same for unpopular.
According my references, if we apply this formula for each point:

- P(P) > 0 and P(U) = 0; classified as popular
- P(U) > 0 and P(P) = 0; classified as unpopular
- Any other result will be undefined.

Is this the best approach for my goal? Should I apply a different methodology?

In case this is the best way to classify my points, how can I program the equation in R in order to avoid NaN problems? As there are points with very high N, I am not able to perform the calculation using:

```
(((r*L)^N)/(factorial(N)))*exp(-r*L)
```

Which could be a modification that will allow me to perform the computation of it maintaining the outcome?

Comment: I find myself longing for a loss function. Can you quantify--if only approximately--the damage that would be caused by mis-classifying any point?  As far as the computational issues go, they are discussed in some other threads here; the bottom line is that you should compute the logarithms (using `lgamma(N+1)` instead of `log(factorial(N))`).

Comment: The solution was to use `ppois()`. Here the [link](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/poisson-distribution) it.